# Get sticky posts from specific category in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, wordpress-theming, archive

I want to check if a category has sticky posts.
To do that, I use `$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );` on the `archive.php`.

But it shows all sticky posts from the blog. Not only from the displayed category.
Is there anything I could add to show only sticky posts from the displayed category or tag?

What I need is a true/false if there are sticky posts. If there are sticky posts I need an array with the IDs.

Comment: Hope this will help : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190474/sticky-posts-for-each-category-archive-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope the below code will help you :

```
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
    $args = array(
        'cat' => 3,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 0,
        'post__in' => $sticky,
        'paged' => $paged
    );
    $sticky_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $sticky_posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $sticky_posts->have_posts() ) : 
       $sticky_posts->the_post() );
    //Loop markup here
   endwhile; endif;
  //IMPORTANT
wp_reset_postdata();
```

For more help please see this link [click here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts)

Comment: thanks, I edited my question. What I need is a true/false if there are sticky posts. If there are sticky posts I need an array with the IDs.

Comment: see this link i hope it will help you https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/sticky-posts/